# Postscript invalidaccess in def error

Tags: postscript

I am trying to debug some postscript code:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 600 600
/Times-Roman findfont globaldict begin /l0 10 def l0 scalefont setfont    newpath /l1 600 def 4 l1 moveto /l2 l1 def /l3 { /l4 exch def /l2 l2 l0 sub def 10 l2 moveto l4 show } bind def
```

I get this error:

```
Error: /invalidaccess in --def--
Operand stack:
   l3   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--       -nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1976   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1960   1   3   %oparray_pop   1852   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2    --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
GPL Ghostscript 9.18: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1191/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:3/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--      --dict:3/20(G)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 234
```

Having read some documentation I am to believe this is caused by trying to put a composite type (the procedure enclosed in the curly braces) onto the globaldict which is read-only and apparently /invalidaccess means you can't put local objects onto global dicts anyway.

Could anyway advise what code to add or takeaway to make this bit of postscript run?

Many thanks

Comment: Don't use globaldict, to put it simply. You should never be using this dictionary. Use userdict instead, that's what its there for.

Answer (score 2):

Ken's answer is correct. This answer is just more details of what is going on here.

There is a rule in level 2 and higher PostScript that global virtual memory cannot contain references to local virtual memory. (Level 1 had only local memory.)

So, the correct way to put an array (like a procedure) in `globaldict` is to allocate it in global memory.

```
globaldict begin
  currentglobal true setglobal
    /l3 { /l4 exch def /l2 l2 l0 sub def 10 l2 moveto l4 show } bind def
  setglobal
end
```

But of course, you don't need to use global memory in any 'normal' postscript
coding. If you're defining Named Resources or installing resident code into a printer, then you might need to do these gymnastics. Or if ... by some strange chance ... you're working with Display PostScript which uses multiple threads of execution then you might need global memory to communicate between threads.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use globaldict, to put it simply. You should never be using this dictionary.

Use userdict instead, that's what its there for. You don't even need to do 'userdict begin' because userdict is the current dictionary when you start a PostScript program, you actually have to take deliberate action to change it.

Comment: That's overly simplistic. globaldict is there for a reason, quoted from the language reference: "In  a  hierarchically  structured  program  such  as  a  page  description,  local  VM  isused to hold information whose lifetime conforms to the structure; that is, it per-sists to the end of a structural division, such as a single page."
If you want to do somethin like adding document page numbers, you need globaldict.